# How to display the difference between two DNA Sequences via command line tools

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have the following problem:

My data sheet looks like this

```
AAAGGGTTT AAAGGG
AAAGGGCCC GGGCCC
```

and I want to display the difference between the two sequences in the third row like this

```
AAAGGGTTT AAAGGG TTT
AAAGGGCCC GGGCCC AAA
```

what I've tried is to use diff. I extracted the individual sequences in files (f1.txt and f2.txt) and formatted them so they could be compared line by line with diff which created the problem that it only works when the start of the sequence is similar (Line 1 of datasheet).

```
awk '{gsub(".","&\n");printf "%s",$0}' < f1.txt >f1a.txt
awk '{gsub(".","&\n");printf "%s",$0}' < f2.txt >f2a.txt
 
diff -y f1a.txt f2a.txt
```

does anyone have an idea how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Does a "sequence" contain the space? Or is that second column something else that the problem you've described can just ignore?

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you are after?

```
awk '{$3=$1;sub($2,"",$3)}1' file
```

- `$3=$1` copies the 1st field to the 3rd field  and
- `sub($2,"",$3)` looks for the 2nd field in the 3rd field. If there is a match, `sub` substitutes the matched string by a null string in the 3rd field.
- The `1` at the end prints the result. It is equivalent to a `{print}` statement, so you could rewrite it as `{$3=$1;sub($2,"",$3);print}`.

The result:

```
AAAGGGTTT AAAGGG TTT
AAAGGGCCC GGGCCC AAA
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining your syntax a bit more for me? What does the "" and the 1 at the end do? I'm new to bash and always thankful for more insight

Comment: @DanielR Glad to help, see the edit for clarification. Also, bear in mind this has only to do with awk. Bash does not do anything special here.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to display pairwise alignments of sequences, use the appropriate bioinformatics tools. The sequence alignment will show differences in formats expected by the typical users. Here, for pairwise alignment of nucleotide sequence, you can use, for example, `blastn` from the BLAST tools (which can be installed, for example, using `conda`), see this command from the thread: https://www.biostars.org/p/18087/#18095 :

```
blastn -query querySeqSet.fasta -subject targetSeqSet.fasta
```

Comment: Idk anything about these tools, but +1 for right tool for the job

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am looking specifically for the bases that are not aligned